# unable to pause shoutcast url using HTMLAudioElement

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, shoutcast

I have created my `audio` url as follows

```
this.stream = new Audio("http://ip:port/;");
```

Unable to pause the stream

**Pause Method**

```
this.stream.pause();
```

also tried to clear the `src` and also set `currentTime=0` and `preload="none"`
but none of them works , audio stream is continuously playing after Pause-ing also

Comment: What browser are you using?  And, is that all of the relevant code?  If so, can you post a link to the stream?  I've never had this issue... in particular, clearing `src` or nuking the audio element entirely should solve it.

Comment: @Brad , i'm developing a hybrid mobile app, which in turn uses a  Webview, so im targetting for iOS, so its webview might be related to safari i guess , yes , that is all the relevant code .. here is my stream                              
 [link](http:183.82.98.147:11020/)